# PHPunit, Symfony2 & AWS SDK - Can't load APC or xcache

Tags: symfony, phpunit, apc, xcache

I've hit a roadblock with my phpunit functional tests. The AWS SDK requires APC, for some reason I can't get phpunit to load the extension. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The CLI is using the same ini file as MAMP

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:HvH-PHP greg$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:HvH-PHP greg$
```

I've also attempted to add the ini file into `app/phpunit.xml.dist`

```
<php>
    <ini name="mamp" value="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini"/>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
</php>
```

**Error message in CLI**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apc_fetch() in /vendor/aws-sdk-for-php/lib/cachecore/cacheapc.class.php on line 58
```

**EDIT: Some more test as per comments**
In CLI I can run a test script with `apc_fetch();` and it works successfully.

Running `php -m` also shows APC as an installed module

Any suggestions as to what else I should try?

Comment: `php -i |grep -i apc` and/or `php -m`

Comment: first command returned a bunch of APC info, all looks good. Here are the first four lines: `apc
APC Support => disabled

APC Debugging => Disabled

apc.cache_by_default => On => On

apc.canonicalize => On => On`

Comment: php -m also shows APC: `php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
`

Comment: what if you create script `<?php apc_fetch();` and run it using `php -f testscript.php`?

Comment: works fine, i tried with that and did not get a response, then tried again with a deliberately miss-spelt version and i got the error.

Comment: So what and how do you run? How is it different from `php -f testscript.php`?

Comment: what if you put `var_dump(get_loaded_extensions()); exit;` in any phpunit test and check if there is APC loaded when you run phpunit? If not - replace it with `phpinfo();` and check what config file has been loaded

Comment: ahh good call. That's the problem it's not using the MAMP ini file. How do I tell phpunit to use that ini file? I thought I have already specified that in the params xml (see question) Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /private/etc/php.ini

Comment: Uhm, that's strange. Where `/private/etc/php.ini` comes from? On my installation I have the same ini-file loaded for generic CLI run and phpunit

Comment: hrmmm. I guess that ini file is the generic osx file. I use mamp and I originally had to update my .profile to add the mamp php.ini onto the path var so I could us it in cli.

Comment: as a temporary solution you could create a symlink of `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini` to `/private/etc/php.ini`, because I cannot find possibility of specifying ini-file for phpunit explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could propose you 2 solutions:

1. Create a symlink of `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini` to `/private/etc/php.ini`
2. Modify `phpunit` execution file and append `-c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/` to the php run command. Also - check if correct php binary is used. If it is not - change to the correct path first and check if issue has been fixed

Comment: @whistlergreg: which way did you follow?

Comment: Symlink did the trick. A little bit of a hack but that doesn't bother me. Thanks for working me through the problem!